# Better way from byte[] to byte*

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, unsafe

Is there a better way?  Please note that I'm not using `fixed` because I need to scan through the buffer data.

```
GCHandle pinned1 = GCHandle.Alloc(Pic1, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr ptr1 = pinned1.AddrOfPinnedObject();
byte* p1 = (byte*)ptr1.ToPointer();
//...
//...
//...
byte a=*p1;
p1++;
//...
//...
pinned1.Free();
```

Comment: Is this buffer being shared with unmanaged code?  If not, then `fixed` should probably be fine or even using standard, safe techniques to iterate/loop through the array without pointers.  Coming up with something 'better' needs more information about what you're really doing.

Comment: using fixed wont let me do p1++;  also, something tells me that iterating with pointer is much faster than iterating with array index.  didn't measure, legacy thinking, I guess.

Comment: Really?  It works for me - see this sample from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28k1s2k6.aspx

Comment: de-fixing it did the trick.  thx @dtb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way: use `fixed`.

You can simply assign the pointer to another variable and perform pointer arithmetic on that:

```
fixed (byte* ptr = pic1)
{
    byte* p1 = ptr;

    //...
    byte a = *p1;
    p1++;
    //...
}
```